# Does HTTP connection close or drop are not logged?

Tags: http, tomcat, https, openssl, tomcat7

After switching to HTTPS communication from Nginx to Tomcat, we're seeing lots of exceptions in tomcat log about,

> closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify, and 
>   connection or outbound has closed

Does only HTTPS related connection loss are logged? Not HTTP?

Comment: This is an HTTPS error. You don't need to log normal connection loss, as it isn't an error.

Comment: Right, so basically connection loss occurs anyway. It is because the design of HTTPS is socket based, that it tries to close on the open socket and doesn't get close notification it throws an error.

Comment: It is logged because this sequence of events represents a possible TLS truncation attack.